# Problems with queuing jQuery Effects with jQuery UI Effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm really confused when it comes to queuing jQuery Effects and jQuery UI Effects. When I do

```
$('#div_id').effect('bounce').effect('shake').fadeOut();
```

the div bounces first than fades out but shake is omitted.

Calling

```
$('#div_id').effect('bounce').effect('shake');
```

everything works like I expected it (first bounce than shake).

Also

```
$('#div_id').effect('bounce').fadeOut();
```

works just like expected

here is a full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    var square = $('#square');

    $("#button_1").click(function() {
      square.effect('bounce'); // ok
    });

    $("#button_2").click(function() {
      square.effect('bounce').effect('shake'); // ok (bounces first, than shakes)
    });

    $("#button_3").click(function() {
      square.effect('bounce').fadeOut(); // ok (bounces first, than fades out)
    });

    $("#button_4").click(function() {
      square.effect('bounce').effect('shake').fadeOut(); // fail (bounces first, than fades out)
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
  <div id="square" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; position: relative;"></div>

  <button id="button_1">bounce</button>
  <button id="button_2">bounce shake</button>
  <button id="button_3">bounce fadeOut</button>
  <button id="button_4">bounce shake fadeOut</button>
</body>
</html>
```

any help is highly appreciated

thanks Björn

Comment: funny..I notice that it _shakes_ but after fadding-out, because it does not _go-out_ till sometime in which it shakes..here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifzbaig/tnwRq/)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the beaviour seems to be a bug in jQuery

a possible workaround is

```
$('#div_id').effect('bounce').effect('shake',function(){$(this).fadeOut()});
```

thanks to everyone for contributing and helping out!

Answer (score 2):

you can put the callback in `#button_4`

```
$("#button_4").click(function() {
      square.effect('bounce',function(){
            $(this).effect('shake',{ times:3 }, 300).fadeOut()          
      });
});
```

example: [working example ..maybe ^_^](http://jsfiddle.net/goonie/xfKvL/)

explain:  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

Comment: Thanks - I know I can do this but I was still wondering why it's not possible by simply chaining calls on the jQuery object.

Comment: I am sorry but this is also not working..[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifzbaig/tnwRq/1/)

Comment: @Goonie Yes I saw it..:) But I don't know what is actually happening here that chaining in JQuery UI is working fine but whenever I try to work with `fadeOut()` in chaining it does not work with more than one effect prior to it..you can see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/asifzbaig/wPzZU/7/) that _bounce-shake-bounce_ works, but _bounce-shake-fadeOut_ NOT...Any special reason behind it? Is JQuery does not allow chaining? Do we have to use callback always with JQuery functions?

Comment: @Asif I don't know exactly, i think that the problem is on fadeOut.. it don't like chainig very well, maybe it can accept only one effect before invoke it and not waiting the execution of previous animation. Invoke it on callback could resolve the issue and forces it to start after .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's wrong there, however i recomend using callback explicitly like this:

```
var square = $('#square');

$("#button_1").click(function() {
  square.effect('bounce'); // ok
});

$("#button_2").click(function() {
  square.effect('bounce').effect('shake'); // ok (bounces first, than shakes)
});

$("#button_3").click(function() {
  square.effect('bounce').fadeOut(); // ok (bounces first, than fades out)
});

$("#button_4").click(function() {
    square.effect('bounce').effect('shake',function(){$(this).fadeOut()});
});​
```

**Update**

I just updated the code for a working solution.

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPzZU/6/)

Comment: Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifzbaig/wPzZU/4/) of mine and compare with your one..

Comment: ok - the last fiddle is working... still - my question was asked to understand why it's not working to chain the calls. So is it a bug? Or is it not intended to be called like I did?

Comment: Not sure, using the callback only before the fadeOut works fine. I would say it's a bug. http://jsfiddle.net/wPzZU/6/